# Is there any way to run part of a SQL azure statement outside a transaction scope

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, transactions, azure-sql-database

I need to create a fulltext index for a database deployment and the deployment process involves a versioning software (flyway, for those interested) which runs everything in a transaction. [T-SQL does not allow this in a transaction.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191544(v=sql.105).aspx)

The "proper" solution here is to get flyway to run my updates outside of a transaction. It might have that capability, but there is no documentation nor examples. You can see the relevant GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1072)

I want to try to bypass this issue altogether and just hack my SQL updates into the current process, which lead my to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36858081/t-sql-equivalent-of-net-transactionscopeoption-suppress), the answer to which explains that a loopback linked server can execute a remote procedure call from within a transaction but not carry the transaction scope to that execution.

Sounds like exactly what I want but now I am confronted by [no support for sp_addlinkedserver in SQL Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435621/create-a-linked-server-in-sql-azure-database).

Does anyone know a way to run an autonomous transaction in sql azure?

Comment: Does it need to be in an autonomous transaction or can you commit the previous one, do your thing then open a new one?

Comment: I did attempt that just by committing before my code and opening a new transaction after creating the index but I received the same error as before

Comment: What's the error text?

Comment: `CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX statement cannot be used inside a user transaction.`